# Foreign key C# MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

I would like to relate a string field as a foreign key, I need help please!

catalogtype.code => catalog.typeCatalogRefCode

```
public class CatalogType : AuditFields
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

}

public class Catalog : AuditFields
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string typeCatalogRefCode { get; set; }
    public virtual CatalogType catalogType { get; set; }
}
```

.........................................................................

```
public class AuditFields
{
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string createdIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string modifiedIn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following class structure. For making "typeCatalogRefCode" as foreign key you need to define "code" as key

```
class MyDBContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("mydbcontext")
    {

    }
    static MyDBContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
}

public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogTypes{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Catalog> Catalogs{ get; set; }
}
public class CatalogType : AuditFields
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
            [Key]
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

}

public class Catalog : AuditFields
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string typeCatalogRefCode { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("typeCatalogRefCode")]
    public virtual CatalogType catalogType { get; set; }
}
public class AuditFields
{
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string createdIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string modifiedIn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not find another way to do more than alter the structure of my table by changing the code as the primary key. Even the code with the annotation Index [IsUnique = true] did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for this you need to write code on override method OnModelCreating of your dbcontext class. Please refer the following code.

```
public class CatalogContext : DbContext
{
    static CatalogContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CatalogContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogTypes{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Catalog> Catalogs{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Entity<Catalog>().HasOptional(a=>a.catalogType)
                            .WithMany(au=>au.Catalogs)
                            .HasForeignKey(a=>typeCatalogRefCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote up. You could also add the way to achieve it with data annotations

Comment: An error occurred while generating the migration: Catalog_catalogType_Target_Catalog_catalogType_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'typeCatalogRefCode' on entity 'Catalog' does not match the type of property 'id' on entity 'CatalogType' in the referential constraint 'Catalog_catalogType'.

Comment: what is your AuditFields class please share... @Hilarioc

Comment: I shared the AuditFild class.

Answer (score 0):

Koderzzzz answer is right but just to complete you can also use data annotation :

```
public class CatalogType : AuditFields
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("catalogType")]
    public ICollection<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

}

public class Catalog : AuditFields
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string typeCatalogRefCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("typeCatalogRefCode")]
    public virtual CatalogType catalogType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do the same with annotations: 
CatalogType_Catalogs_Source_CatalogType_Catalogs_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'typeCatalogRefCode' on entity 'Catalog' does not match the type of property 'id' on entity 'CatalogType' in the referential constraint 'CatalogType_Catalogs'.